# My custom NPM Package is not found

Tags: node.js, npm

Got very strange issues. Basically i decided create my own npm package, and publish it to the world. During development, I was testing it as s simple node module, and was able to use it using next code:

```
var r = require('./lib/%mymodulename%');
```

Of course it was in the lib folder.

Now, I organised it as a npm package, and my package.json looks next:

```
{
  "name": "mymodulename",
  "author": "xxx",
  "description": "xxx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "homepage": "xxx",

  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "xxx"
  },

  "main": "/lib/mymodulename.js",

  "scripts": {
    "install":"node install.js"
  },

  "dependencies": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.9"
  }

}
```

when i am trying to test it via : `npm install . -g` it is installed successfully and i am able to see my local module via:

```
npm ls -g
```

however, when i am trying to use it in node file like:

`var r = require('mymodulename')` npm can't find it.

I think that i am missing something very small, but can't find what.

Thanks,
-D

Comment: > These are mostly for historic reasons. You are highly encouraged to place your dependencies locally in node_modules folders. They will be loaded faster, and more reliably.
http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

Comment: I suspect you are missing an index.js as part of your module. Take a look at the "Directories as modules" here http://book.mixu.net/node/ch8.html

Comment: `main` must hold a relative path. Try removing the leading `/`. Note: you must have a js file at `lib/mymodulename.js` under the package root dir.

Answer (score 1):

Ok! Thanks for the answers.

It was totally my fault, and never put `/` for the `main`.

In my case i got :

```
 "main": "/lib/mymodulename.js",
```

and it should be:

```
 "main": "lib/mymodulename.js",
```

Thanks!